# Konjunktiv und Indikativ in einem Satz mischen in Paraphrase

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

Ich sitze gerade an einer Hausarbeit und bin mir bezüglich der Verwendung des Konjunktivs unsicher. Es geht um einen Absatz, in dem ich die Gedanken eines Autors paraphrasiere. Ich habe z.B. geschrieben:

> Dies signalisiere Fehler, welche kritisch sind.

Mit dem ganzen Satz beziehe ich mich weiterhin auf den Autor. Ist es in diesem Fall falsch, den Nebensatz im indikativ zu schreiben? Alternativ habe ich daran gedacht, den Nebensatz auch im Konjunktiv zu schreiben:

> Dies signalisiere Fehler, welche kritisch seien.

Was wäre die grammatikalisch oder stilistich richtige Form?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Und hier haben wir ein Musterbeispiel dafür, warum man keine Antworten in Kommentaren schreiben sollte, auch wenn sie nur besagen, dass etwas korrekt/inkorrekt ist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wenn die komplette Aussage ein Zitat ist, sind beide Satzteile indirekte Rede und müssen demnach auch beide im Konjunktiv stehen:

> Dies signalisiere Fehler, welche kritisch seien.

Zur Verdeutlichung:

> Peter sagte: "Ich gehe jetzt nach Hause und lege mich schlafen."
>
> Peter sagte, er gehe jetzt nach Hause, wo er sich schlafen lege.

Ebenso:

> Peter sagte: "Dies signalisiert kritische Fehler."
>
> Peter sagte, dies signalisiere Fehler, welche kritisch seien.

---

Ob du diese Aussage in der von dir gewählten Konstruktion aus Haupt- und Nebensatz paraphrasierst oder in einem einzelnen Hauptsatz, bleibt dir überlassen, beide sind gleichbedeutend:

> Dies signalisiere Fehler, welche kritisch seien.
>
> Dies signalisiere kritische Fehler.
>
> Dies signalisiere Fehler, und Fehler seien kritisch.
>
> Dies signalisiere Fehler. Fehler seien kritisch.

Und so weiter. Es kann allerdings Sinn machen, die grammatische Konstruktion des Originals zu übernehmen, wenn es dir darauf ankommt, die Denkweise des zitierten Autors zu verdeutlichen.

---

Falls der zweite Satzteil kein Zitat sein sollte – du also sagen möchtest, dass *du* Fehler kritisch findest – würde ich den Wechsel des Sprechers deutlich machen:

> Dies signalisiere Fehler, welche m.E. kritisch sind.

Stilistisch besser wäre in diesem Fall allerdings ein neuer Satz:

> Dies signalisiere Fehler. Und Fehler sind kritisch.

So wird deutlich, dass der erste Satz ein Zitat, der zweite deine Meinung ist.